# Get Position of UIImageView - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiimageview

So I know about image.center, but when I do something like this:

```
    image.frame = CGRectMake(image.center.x, image.center.y, image.frame.size.width, image.frame.size.height);
```

The image moves down and right. I believe this is happening because it is getting the x and y coordinates of the center of the image, but is there a way to get the top left coordinates so that the above code doesn't move the image?

Comment: The reason you would change a view's frame is to either move it, resize it, or both.  What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the stick's frame to be the frame of image, the easiest way is the following:

```
stick.frame = image.frame;
```

Just for your information, what you were originally looking for is the frame.origin, which is a CGPoint including the x and y origin's:

```
stick.frame = CGRectMake(image.frame.origin.x, image.frame.origin.y, image.frame.size.width, image.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Oh oops. All the "image" were "stick." I just changed them to make it easier to understand. See my edit please.

Comment: Based on your edit, you're setting the image's frame to the image's frame?

Comment: Yeah, but when I do this, the image moves. Basically, I want to find the exact top left x and y coordinates of a UIImageView.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. Do you want to just get the frame for the image view, or do you want to set the image view's frame as the frame for something else?